# Creating QML States dynamically

Tags: qt, qml

I want to make an icon component that changes it picture and color depending on it state:

`StateIcon.qml:`

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

Item {
    Layout.preferredWidth: appLayout.icon.prefWidth
    Layout.preferredHeight: appLayout.icon.prefHeight

    property variant stateImage: stateImageInstance
    Image {
        id: stateImageInstance
        width: appLayout.icon.prefWidth
        height: appLayout.icon.prefWidth

        sourceSize.width: width
        sourceSize.height: height
    }

    property variant imageOverlay: imageOverlayInstance
    ColorOverlay {
        id: imageOverlayInstance
        anchors.fill: stateImage
        source: stateImage
    }

    transitions: Transition {
        SequentialAnimation {
            NumberAnimation {
                target: stateImage; property: "scale"
                to: 0; duration: 100
            }
            PropertyAction {
                target: stateImage; property: "source"
            }
            PropertyAction {
                target: imageOverlay; property: "color"
            }
            NumberAnimation {
                target: stateImage; property: "scale"
                to: 1; duration: 100
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I have to define states in the component instance:

`main.qml:`

```
StateIcon {
    id: stateIcon
    states: [
        State {
            name: "state1";
            PropertyChanges {
                target: stateIcon.stateImage
                source: "qrc:/resources/icons/icon1.svg"
            }
            PropertyChanges {
                target: stateIcon.imageOverlay; color: "gray"
            }

        },
        State {
            name: "state2";
            PropertyChanges {
                target: stateIcon.stateImage
                source: "qrc:/resources/icons/icon2.svg"
            }
            PropertyChanges {
                target: stateIcon.imageOverlay; color: "green"
            }
        }
        ...
    ]

    state: "state1"
}
```

And now I want to know is it possible to define only state names, color and source in some array:

`main.qml:`

```
StateIcon {
    id: stateIcon
    rawStates: [
           {
               name: "state1",
               iconSource: "qrc:/resources/icons/state1.svg",
               color: "green"
           },
           {
               name: "state2",
               iconSource: "qrc:/resources/icons/state2.svg",
               color: "green"
           },
           ...
       ]

    state: "state1"
}
```

And in the `StateIcon.qml` define `states` property dynamically using `rawStates` property?

Maybe something like that:

`StateIcon.qml:`

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

Item {
    property variant rawStates

    Layout.preferredWidth: appLayout.icon.prefWidth
    Layout.preferredHeight: appLayout.icon.prefHeight

    Image {
        id: stateImage
        width: appLayout.icon.prefWidth
        height: appLayout.icon.prefWidth

        sourceSize.width: width
        sourceSize.height: height
    }

    ColorOverlay {
        id: imageOverlay
        anchors.fill: stateImage
        source: stateImage
    }

    states: [
        for(var i=0; i<rawStates.length; ++i) {
            ?
        }
    ]

    transitions: Transition {
        SequentialAnimation {
            NumberAnimation {
                target: stateImage; property: "scale"
                to: 0; duration: 100
            }
            PropertyAction {
                target: stateImage; property: "source"
            }
            PropertyAction {
                target: imageOverlay; property: "color"
            }
            NumberAnimation {
                target: stateImage; property: "scale"
                to: 1; duration: 100
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried a `Instantiator` to create the states, and stuff them into `states`? I have no clue if it is possible, but have to little time to try it right now.

Comment: I've tried to create `states` array using `Components`. But I don't succeed in. Maybe someone other be able to do it.

Comment: Why do you need to use states here ? You could easily do that with an associative array property.

Comment: @GrecKo Can you write a little sample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `States` I would use a plain javascript associative arrays.
You can't use `transitions` but you could use `Behavior` instead. Not anything can be done with behavior but it's enough most of the time.

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQml 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainWindow
    visible: true
    minimumWidth: 500
    minimumHeight: 500

    Row {
        Rectangle {
            id: rect
            width: 100
            height: 100

            property var stateDescriptors: {
                'state0': {color: 'green'},
                'state1': {color: 'red'},
                'state2': {color: 'blue'},
                'state3': {color: 'purple'},
                'state4': {color: 'orange'}
            }
            property string iconState: "state0"

            Text {
                anchors.fill: parent
                text: parent.iconState
            }
            color: stateDescriptors[iconState].color
            Behavior on iconState {
                SequentialAnimation {
                    NumberAnimation {
                        target: rect; property: "scale"
                        to: 0; duration: 100
                    }
                    PropertyAction { } //actually change the iconState here, since the color is binded to it, it will also change between the 2 scale animations
                    NumberAnimation {
                        target: rect; property: "scale"
                        to: 1; duration: 100
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Button {
            text: 'change state'
            property int count: 0
            onClicked: {
                count = (count + 1) % Object.keys(rect.stateDescriptors).length
                rect.iconState = 'state' + count
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps you:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQml 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainWindow
    visible: true
    minimumWidth: 500
    minimumHeight: 500

    Row {
        Rectangle {
            id: rect
            width: 100
            height: 100

            Text {
                anchors.fill: parent
                text: parent.state
            }

            property var myStates: []
            states: myStates

            onStateChanged: console.log(Object.keys(rect.states))
        }

        Button {
            text: 'add state'
            onClicked: {
                rect.myStates.push(statePrototype.createObject(rect,
                                                           {
                                                               name: 'state' + count,
                                                               color: Qt.rgba(Math.random(count),
                                                                              Math.random(count),
                                                                              Math.random(count),
                                                                              Math.random(count))
                                                           }))
                rect.myStatesChanged()
                count++
            }
        }

        Button {
            text: 'change state'
            onClicked: {
                rect.state = 'state' + (count1 % count)
                count1++
            }
        }

    }

    property int count: 0
    property int count1: 0
    Component {
        id: statePrototype
        State {
            id: st
            property color color
            PropertyChanges {
                target: rect
                color: st.color
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It seems to be not so easily possible to add `State`s to `states` directly. With the extra mile going over a custom `property var myStates` it suddenly works. *Don't forget to tell everyone, that `myStatesChanged()` after adding something!*

**EDIT** *Once more, with the list of JS Objects, and a Instantiator. The method is the same*

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQml 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainWindow
    visible: true
    minimumWidth: 500
    minimumHeight: 500

    Row {
        Rectangle {
            id: rect
            width: 100
            height: 100

            Text {
                anchors.fill: parent
                text: parent.state
            }



            property var myStates: []
            states: myStates
            onStateChanged: console.log(Object.keys(rect.states))
        }

        Button {
            text: 'change state'
            property int count: 0
            onClicked: {
                rect.state = 'state' + count % rect.myStates.length
                count ++
            }
        }

        Button {
            text: 'add states'
            onClicked: {
                stateDescriptors.push( { name: 'state' + stateDescriptors.length, color: Qt.rgba(Math.random(1),
                                                                                                        Math.random(2),
                                                                                                        Math.random(3),
                                                                                                        Math.random(4)) })
                stateDescriptorsChanged()
            }
        }
    }

    Instantiator {
        model: stateDescriptors
        delegate: State {
            name: modelData.name
            PropertyChanges {
                target: rect
                color: modelData.color
            }
            Component.onCompleted: {
                console.log('created', modelData.name)
                rect.myStates.push(this)
                rect.myStatesChanged()
            }
            Component.onDestruction: {
                console.log('destroy', modelData.name)
                rect.myStates.pop()
            }
        }
    }

    property var stateDescriptors: [
        {
            name: 'state0',
            color: 'green'
        },

        {
            name: 'state1',
            color: 'red'
        },

        {
            name: 'state2',
            color: 'blue'
        },

        {
            name: 'state3',
            color: 'purple'
        },

        {
            name: 'state4',
            color: 'orange'
        }
    ]
}
```