# How to use a StateMachine repeatedly over a different element?

Tags: qt, qml

The Column with id:signal1 uses the StateMachine. How to apply the same State to the Column with id:signal2 or more identical ones if required in future.

Below is from Lights.ui.qml.
Should anything be done in the C++, or should I modify the Qml file.

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import TrafficLightStateMachine 1.0

Image {
   id: lights

property TrafficLightStateMachine stateMachine

source: "background.png"

states: [
    State {
        name: "Red"
        when: stateMachine.red

        PropertyChanges {
            target: redLight
            opacity: 1
        }
    },
    State {
        name: "RedGoingGreen"
        when: stateMachine.redGoingGreen

        PropertyChanges {
            target: redLight
            opacity: 1
        }

        PropertyChanges {
            target: yellowLight
            opacity: 1
        }
    },
    State {
        name: "Yellow"
        when: stateMachine.yellow

        PropertyChanges {
            target: yellowLight
            opacity: 1
        }
    },
    State {
        name: "Green"
        when: stateMachine.green

        PropertyChanges {
            target: greenLight
            opacity: 1
        }
    }
]
Column {
    id: signal1
    y: 286
    width: 22
    height: 120
    layer.smooth: true
    layer.enabled: false
    rotation: 0
    transformOrigin: Item.Center
    anchors.horizontalCenterOffset: -87
    spacing: 27
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter

    Image {
        id: redLight
        width: 20
        height: 20
        opacity: 0.2
        source: "red.png"
    }

    Image {
        id: yellowLight
        width: 20
        height: 20
        opacity: 0.2
        layer.smooth: true
        layer.enabled:false
        source: "yellow.png"
    }

    Image {
        id: greenLight
        width: 20
        height: 20
        opacity: 0.2
        source: "green.png"
    }
}

Column {
    id: signal2
    x: -8
    y: 237
    width: 22
    height: 120
    spacing: 27
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    anchors.horizontalCenterOffset: 124
    rotation: 270
    transformOrigin: Item.Center
    Image {
        id: redLight1
        width: 20
        height: 20
        opacity: 0.2
        source: "red.png"
    }

    Image {
        id: yellowLight1
        width: 20
        height: 20
        opacity: 0.2
        source: "yellow.png"
    }

    Image {
        id: greenLight1
        width: 20
        height: 20
        opacity: 0.2
        source: "green.png"
    }
}
```

The below image shows a signal1 that is using the state diagram , I want the other signal on the right i.e signal2 also to use the same state diagram? Will that be possible?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkzLb.png

Can you please help me out with this ?

Comment: "_The Column with id:signal1 uses the StateMachine..._" - I actually see no state machine usage for this specified item.

Comment: Can you please tell me the approach that can be followed otherwise  ---actually the image id  redLight matches with the target under the propertyChange. That worked fine for the Column signal1 but I am not sure how it can be done in signal2

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42997805/creating-qml-states-dynamically) question

Comment: It seems you are working on the same homework as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72667683/how-to-draw-a-gui-window-with-minimum-signals-and-timer-options ? Anyway, you should move the Column to it's own QML file so that is can be reused and all the states can be defined once in the new QML file